# Coherence Cache Cluster Status using .Net

Tags: .net, oracle-coherence

How do I know the current status of Coherence cache for a .Net client? I do get the MemberLeft events, but nothing seems to be in the API to give a cluster status as such?

Answer (score 2):

Normally, the information about cluster status etc. would be obtained from the JMX "mbeans".

So, just to be certain, are you trying to access information about the Coherence cluster from a .NET client?

If so, then you probably want to execute an entry processor from the .NET client that will go into the cluster, collect the mbean info, and send it back.